# How can Lloyd's Algorithm be used to spread the points used throughout the shape shown below, or is there a better algorithm/method?

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, voronoi-diagram

https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/333756/199881.

[image: This one right here]

I am not sure how the centroid part would work, as it looks like it will land outside the cell. By Lloyd's Algorithm, I mean as shown [here](http://www.bitbanging.space/posts/lloyds-algorithm).

Comment: Intersect Voronoi regions with the polygon and compute the centroid of the intersection.

Comment: @Ihf Won't the centroid of the intersection go outside of the polygon for some? Or is there another way to find the centroid, like the visual centroid discussed here: https://blog.mapbox.com/a-new-algorithm-for-finding-a-visual-center-of-a-polygon-7c77e6492fbc

Comment: Oh, yes, that could happen.

Comment: @Ihf Will the centroids eventually go back within the boundaries of the polygon, by any chance?

Comment: I don't know... You may try projecting the centroid onto the closest edge when the centroid is outside.

Comment: See also the paper [Re-tiling polygonal surfaces](https://doi.org/10.1145/133994.134008), which uses triangulations.